# Проблема с NoSuchElementException в месте где ее быть не должно

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть следующий код, на первый взгляд, вроде выглядит нормально:

```
override fun onItemClick(deepLink: String, position: Int) {
             //...

            val item: Center? = items.asSequence().filterIndexed { index, any ->
                    index == position && any is Center
                }.map {
                    it as Center
                }.firstOrNull()

            //...
}
```

Но при этом стреляет

> kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.first (_Sequences.kt:110)
>   com.hily.app.presentation.ui.fragments.center.presenters.CenterPresenter.onItemClick
>   (CenterPresenter.kt:385)
>   com.hily.app.presentation.ui.adapters.recycle.CenterRecyclerAdapter$ItemViewHolder$bind$2.onClick
>   (CenterRecyclerAdapter.kt:109) android.view.View.performClick
>   (View.java:5721)

`firstOrNull()` вроде не должен бросать никаких исключений, думаю причина может быть в `asSequence()`.

**Вопрос:** может ли быть действительно проблема в `asSequence()`,  и как такое зафиксить?

Answer (score 2):

По представленной ошибке в коде _Sequences.kt идёт вызов функции

```
public fun <T> Sequence<T>.first(): T {
    val iterator = iterator()
    if (!iterator.hasNext())
        throw NoSuchElementException("Sequence is empty.")
    return iterator.next()
}
```

а должна вызываться функция из _Sequences.kt firstOrNull

```
public fun <T> Sequence<T>.firstOrNull(): T? {
    val iterator = iterator()
    if (!iterator.hasNext())
        return null
    return iterator.next()
}
```

Как видно во втором случае ошибка возникнуть не должна.

Что можно сделать? 
1)Можно не вызывать asSequence - следующий код работает корректно:

```
open class Center
class CenterChild: Center() {
    val k = 1
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val items = arrayListOf<Center>(Center(), CenterChild())
    val position = 10

    val item: Center? = items
        .filterIndexed { index, any ->
            index == position && any is CenterChild
        }
        .map { it as CenterChild }
        .firstOrNull()
}
```

Вышепредставленный код приведёт к вызову функции firstOrNull из _Collections.kt

```
public fun <T> List<T>.firstOrNull(): T? {
    return if (isEmpty()) null else this[0]
}
```

Как видим - исключений он также не бросает

2)Можно сразу взять нужное значение, а затем проверить его

```
open class Center
class CenterChild: Center() {
    val k = 1
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var items = listOf(Center(), CenterChild(), Object())
    val position = 10
    val item: Any?= items.getOrNull(position)
    if (item != null && item is CenterChild) {
        /* code here */
    }
}
```

Данный код также вызовет метод getOrNull из _Collections.kt

```
public fun <T> List<T>.getOrNull(index: Int): T? {
    return if (index >= 0 && index <= lastIndex) get(index) else null
}
```

Который также не вызывает исключений

Comment: Мне вот тоже интересно откуда взялся вызов `kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.first (_Sequences.kt:110)` , в коде он явно нигде не вызывается,  а `asSequence()` вызываеться для того что бы избежать `ConcurrentModificationException`, оно в подобных случаях у нас тоже стреляло

Comment: `items.asSequence()` создаёт класс `java.util.AbstractList -> Itr`, который не поможет избежать `ConcurrentModificationException`, для устранения данной ошибки нужен либо итератор, который может работать с массивом, который могут в это же время редактировать, либо использовать коллекцию, устойчивую к многопоточности - `val collection = Collections.synchronizedCollection(items);` что позволит избежать вызова `.asSequence()`

Comment: попробуем, а как на счет основного вопроса `SequencesKt___SequencesKt.first (_Sequences.kt:110)` - почему он вызываеться ?

Comment: А какая версия kotlin используется?

Comment: ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'

Comment: Если есть полный стректрейс, по нему наверное легче сказать, в чём дело, иначе даже повторить ошибку не получается))) Если действительно вызывается `.firstOrNull()` , тогда возможно какой-либо подкласс `Iterator` или `Sequence` вызывает метод `.first`. Опять же без стек трейса не получается повторить ошибку

Comment: стектрейс есть, добавил его в вопрос, но он не многословный!

Comment: А можно код данного метода увидеть? `onItemClick (CenterPresenter.kt:385)`

Comment: да, но там ничего касающегося проблемы  - нету, щас обновлю вопрос